# Calculated-String as the parameter to Jenkins's Groovy "STAGE"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I put this in the script section of a Jenkins UI job's configuration -

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('Project') {
    ...
```

That works, however -

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('Project ' + 'Josh') {
    ...
```

throws and displays an incorrect error message because the parser gets all confused due to the constructed string inside the stage.

Moreover,

```
String description = 'Project' + ' Josh'
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages{
        stage(description) {
    ...
```

does not fail, but displays '`description`' as the stage's description.

Now, if you try to load a groovy PaC file with this in it:

```
node {
    stage('Project' + 'Josh') {
    ...
```

it works without a hitch.

Is it possible that there are two different Groovy parsers employed, one for the UI and another for loaded PaC's? This means that the UI one has this really horrible bug in it...

Ideas?
.a.

Comment: Why do you want a dynamic description? Is there a purpose behind it?

Comment: For better documenting the output based on specific dynamic situations...

Answer (score 3):

Your example has nothing to do with Jenkins UI. You have shown two different pipeline types - a **declarative** and **scripted** one.

### Declarative pipeline

A declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // do something here
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

introduces more simplified, limited and opinionated syntax. This type of a pipeline sets boundaries for Groovy code execution - it is only available inside a dedicated `script` block, e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def name = 'Joe'
                    echo "My name is ${name}"
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This is why `stage` block expects a literal and not a variable nor expression.

### Scripted pipeline

The second example you have shown is a scripted pipeline. This kind of pipeline is more powerful comparing to a declarative pipeline - the whole pipeline script is more or less a Groovy script so you can put any code almost everywhere. A scripted pipeline starts with `node` block and it allows you to put any Groovy code inside this block. Consider following example:

```
node {
    stage("Test") {
        echo "1,2,3"
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        stage("Stage ${i}") {
            echo "This is ${i}"
        }
    }
}
```

This pipeline script generates 6 stages:

[image]

As you can see there are actually no limits what kind of stuff you put inside `node` block. Declarative pipeline does not allow you doing that - its syntax is strict and you have to follow it directly.

### Differences

As a final note I will quote Jenkins official docs:

> Where they differ however is in syntax and flexibility. Declarative limits what is available to the user with a more strict and pre-defined structure, making it an ideal choice for simpler continuous delivery pipelines. Scripted provides very few limits, insofar that the only limits on structure and syntax tend to be defined by Groovy itself, rather than any Pipeline-specific systems, making it an ideal choice for power-users and those with more complex requirements. As the name implies, Declarative Pipeline encourages a declarative programming model. Whereas Scripted Pipelines follow a more imperative programming model.
>
> *Source: [https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare_)*

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation! I have tried to put a node where the pipeline was, but then Jenkins complained it has no pipeline (this is for an in-from Jenkins)

Comment: The problem is that in both cases - declarative and scripted, it is still groovy, and there should be no reason for a differing behavior. For example, if you are not supposed to use groovy outside of a script block, why could I define the description variable? Note that inside the stage, i can reference these definitions. So it seems that the parsing of the stage() parameters is incorrect. Does anyone know how to open a defect on it?

Answer (score 1):

The script you configured via UI is using declarative `pipeline` syntax, while the other uses the scripted `node` syntax. I'd say that's probably where the other parser comes in and would agree that the one for `pipeline` has a bug.

Comment: How do we open a defect against Groovy-declarative?